# if else in mysql query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, identifier

Let's say that I want to insert a record in a table. Each record has an ID (not unique)
I want to check two columns (let say first and last name) and if these columns have already been in my table use that id, unless use another id for the new record. 
In other words, I want to say IF the name is new assign a new ID else assign the id of that record. (Don't worry about the new id, assume that I have an original id for each record) 
For example let say I have the following records in my table:

```
FirstName | LastName  | Location | Age ... | ID
John      | Smith     | Canada   | 12 ...  | 1234
John      | Smith     | US       | 21 ...  | 1234
```

And now I want to add another John Smith. So I want the same ID for the new record. While if I want to add Paul Smith, I want a new ID for that.

Comment: It would probably be better to put the first and last name fields in a separate table and make the ID field a foreign key to that table, to avoid duplication of data.

Comment: @Brilliand yes you're right. the user needs to normalized the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (FirstName, LastName, Location, ID)
SELECT new.FirstName, new.LastName, new.Location, IFNULL(present.ID, new.ID)
FROM 
(SELECT 'John' AS FirstName
 , 'Smith' AS LastName
 , 'UK' AS Location
 , 1111 AS ID) AS new
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable AS present
ON present.FirstName = new.FirstName
AND present.LastName = new.LastName
ORDER BY present.ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ce02/9)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to get the current value or use a new one, when that one is missing.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (id, first_name, last_name, other_stuff) VALUES (
    ( SELECT IFNULL (
        ( SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE first_name = 'John' AND last_name = 'Doe'),
        'new_id'
        ),
    ),
    'John',
    'Doe',
    'Your other data'
)
```

Though it does sound to me that you are trying to assign a unique id for every first/last name combination. Depending on your use case there may be better ways to do that (if I am right) like, keep the id <-> name mapping in a separate table for example, and only use the id in the table that you are referring to in this post.

Comment: what if I want to select the data like 'john', 'doe', 'your other data' from another table?

Comment: @AfshinMoazami what you are asking is certainly possible, though I think we are deviating from your original question. I just gave an **example** of using `IFNULL`, and you are free to join a few tables when you do the `SELECT id`, or even use another `SELECT` for 'your other data'.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

You can also specify a different action for duplicate keys to suit your needs.
I believe the fields you are checking against need to be indexed to work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If I define the first name and last name as key, can I have two record with the same key?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` won't do anything unless you have a unique key.

Comment: I've added an example to clarify what I mean

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `names` WHERE `first`=$first AND `last`=$last) THEN (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `names` WHERE `first`=$first AND `last`=$last) ELSE $new_id
```

...is the closest literal answer to your question.  However, in your case, this might be better:

```
IFNULL(SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `names` WHERE `first`=$first AND `last`=$last, $new_id)
```

`CASE WHEN` is an actual if-then-else structure, whereas `IFNULL` (or equivalently, `COALESCE`) just provides a default if nothing is found.

Comment: I think MySQL also has an `IF()` function that works almost the same as `CASE WHEN`.